# Can Octave combine elements and indices in expressions?

Tags: octave

I'd like to create a matrix of elements with each value in column i the ith power of the value in column 1. Easy with a for loop, but is there a way to combine matrix elements and their indices in expressions?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
M = M(:,1) .^ (1:size(M,2));
```

It is easy to generate an array of indices to manipulate and/or operate on.

Note: For older versions of MATLAB the above gives an error, you need to use `bsxfun`:

```
M = bsxfun(@power, M(:,1), 1:size(M,2));
```

Note 2: If your inputs are `v=[3;5;7]` and `n=3` you can translate the above to

```
M = v .^ (1:n);
```

Comment: Sort of, but you're still explicitly specifying the column for assignment (2), and you have no way to reference it in the assignment (you're using the matrix size, not the current column index).  
  
I want to convert ([3; 5; 7], 3) into  
  
3 9 27  
5 25 125  
7 49 243  
  
without a for loop.
  
(Markdown instructions suggest two spaces will give me a line break, but it's not happening. Sorry.)

Comment: @ockham: I mixed up rows and columns, as I'm prone to do. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
F = @(x, n) bsxfun (@realpow, x(:), 1:n);
```

Example:

```
>> F ([3;5;7], 3)
ans =
     3     9    27
     5    25   125
     7    49   343
```